# How can I run a function in index.vue from navbar.vue files

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

So I'm making a select that when you select an option it runs a function. The problem is that the selection in my `navbar.vue` and the function is in `index.vue`.

The function needs to be in the index.vue because it collects a list of products from my database and loads them to my HTML.

Is there any way I could run the function in `index.vue` from `navbar.vue` or run the same function inside the `navbar.vue` but send the output to `index.vue`?

Here is a scheme of how it should work for better understanding:

```
When option selected Navbar.vue --> Runs changeCountry function in index.vue
```

OR

```
When option selected Navbar.vue --> Runs changeCountry function in navbar.vue --> Parses output to index.vue
```

**My code:**

Index.vue:

```
data() {
    return {
      products: null,
      countryCode: 'INT',
    };
  },
created() {
    axios.get(`${baseUrl}/api/popular?country_code=${this.countryCode}`)
      .then((response) => {
        this.products = response.data;
      });
  },
methods: {
    changeCountry(code) {
      axios.get(`${baseUrl}/api/popular?country_code=${code}`)
        .then((response) => {
          this.products = response.data;
        });
    },
  },
```

navbar.vue:

```
<select class="language">
                <option v-for="x in countries" :key="x.value" :value="x.value"
                        :selected="x.value === countryCode" @click="changeCountry(x.value)">
                  {{x.value}}
                </option>
              </select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to make it. The main idea is to pass emit (probably with data) from your Navbar component to index.vue
You can use emit from child to parent or use eventBus(or even $root)
Emit fires by @click or @change (also you can put you variable to watch hook)
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Passing-Data-to-Child-Components-with-Props

Comment: In this case is the child parsing data to parent so that wouldn't work I believe.

Comment: Parent -> index.vue
Child -> Navbar.vue

Comment: Example
Navbar.vue
<select class="language">
                <option v-for="x in countries" :key="x.value" :value="x.value"
                        :selected="x.value === countryCode" @click="changeCountry(x.value)">
                  {{x.value}}
                </option>
              </select>

methods:{
changeCountry(value){
this.$emit("changeCountryFromChild", value)
}
}

Index.vue

<Navbar @changeCountryFromChild:="changeCountry"/>

methods: {
    changeCountry(code) {
     .....
    },
  },

Comment: There is an opportunity  to pass data from child to parent
Parent >> child    with props
child >> parent with emit

Comment: Checked some tutorials on the internet about emit cuz I didn't notice the code but in the end, it worked so thanks for the help.